# Can we stitch Images with out blending

Tags: c++, opencv, blending

I am trying to generate panorama by stitching images. To stitch two frames the code is taking 1 sec and most of the time its take for image warping.
Is it possible to stitch images with out Blending?

Presently I am using Multi band blending

```
MultiBandBlender* mb = dynamic_cast<MultiBandBlender*>(blender.get());
mb->setNumBands(static_cast<int>(ceil(log(blend_width)/log(2.)) - 1.));
```

Can I remove this blending and stitch images?

Comment: Without blending: yes: just use the pixels from one of the images. The result will look not so nice in general. If you have knowledge about your special task, you might be able to develop a very specific and efficient blending. Without warping: no: The images have to be transformed to a shared coordinate system.

Comment: thank you, but is there any sample code for stitching with out blending to which I can refer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stitch two images without blending. But you do this only if you don't care about output.If output matters to you then blending should be done.